# posting to model with ToOneField

Tags: tastypie

I'm new to tastypie and am trying to post to the following model:

```
class UserScore(models.Model):
    """
    User Scores, used to categorise users
    """
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    score    = models.IntegerField()
```

and this is my api:

```
class UserScoreResource(ModelResource):
    category = fields.ForeignKey(CategoryResource, 'category')
    user = fields.OneToOneField(UserResource, 'user')


class Meta:
    queryset = UserScore.objects.all() 
    resource_name = 'score'
    authorization=Authorization()
    allowed_methods = ['post', 'put', 'get']
```

In my unit tests I'm trying to run the following:

```
def test_no_post_to_userscore(self):
    post_data = {
        'user': {'resource_uri':'/api/v1/user/0/'}, 
        'category': {'resource_uri':'/api/v1/category/0/'},
        'score': 50,
    }
    print response.status_code
```

But am receiving a 500 error. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is a syntax issue and unlikely to help others how visit the site.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - bad syntax. Long day

Thanks